# How to run .sh file using CygWin as root in Windows 10?

Tags: shell, cygwin, root

I am trying to run a file with extension ".sh" in Windows 10 using the CygWin Terminal. I ran the following command.

```
$alias sudo="cygstart --action=runas"
$sudo ./fname.sh
```

And I got the following output:

```
Unable to start 'fname.sh': There is no application associated with the 
givenfile name extension.
```

Is there any way to run this file as root using CygWin? 
Or is there any other alternative for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run bash to handle the script

```
 cygstart --action=runas /usr/bin/bash.exe -l <full-path-to>/fname.sh
```